# TraceId and SpanId not available after migrating to Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

After migrating spring boot from version 2.x to 3 we miss traceId and spanId in our logs.

We removed all **sleuth** dependencies and added

```
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
implementation platform('io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bom:latest.release')
```

as well as

```yaml
logging.pattern.level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
```

but no traceIds and spanIds are being logged.

Is there something we missed?

Comment: You can remove the `micrometer-tracing` dependency as it ["is added transitively"](https://micrometer.io/docs/tracing#_installing). Not sure if you need the `micrometer-core`, logs work in my case just with the tracing bridge and actuator as mentioned in the comment below.

Answer (score 8):

You need actuator and a bridge, the rest you included is not needed:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
```

If you also want to report your spans, you should add the zipkin reporter too:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
implementation 'io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave'
```

Here's an example on [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=distributed-tracing,zipkin) and there are a lot of samples in the [micrometer-samples](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples) repo.

Comment: Hi! I'm using your demo project without zipkin report and it doesn't work.
Here is the result:
2023-05-26T22:02:11.632+07:00 " INFO [,,]" 341317 --- [    Test worker] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests

What is may be wrong?

Comment: Found my mistake, missed the need to use the @Observed annotation.

Comment: @VictorBorovlev .. Where to use that Annotation  in our Springboot Application ?

Comment: I tried adding the annotation on the Controller Class and I am getting different TraceIds at my Receiver end . Trace Id are not same in Sender and Receiver Controllers - Any Hint for this issue ?

Comment: @SusheelRao I used annonation io.micrometer.observation.annotation.Observed on Controller class and RestTemplate or WebClient for request another application and it is work fine. Also i use CurrentTraceContext for get trace id in ControllerAdvice class and put in error dto.